# Django 1.7 Unittests not discovered unless I specify app

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-1.7

I have the following folder structure:

```
apps/core/
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    └── test_models.py
```

I'm using `manage.py` with a specific settings file then the following code is executed:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'core.tests',
)
```

This works fine and `core.tests.models` is run and a table is created for my test-only model. Intentional errors or print lines within `tests.models` execute as expected.

However `test_models.py` code is not executed at all, including print statements or intentional code errors in the root of the file.

If I specify the core app such as `manage.py test core` however then the tests within `test_models.py` is run.

Comment: Have you tried importing the various test files in __init__.py?